# Single word for denoting "various divisions of the day"

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the category name to describe “day”, “night”, or “dusk”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97129/what-is-the-category-name-to-describe-day-night-or-dusk)

What would be the hypernym for the various divisions of the day such as *morning, noon, evening* or *night*?

Comment: related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28498/precise-names-for-parts-of-a-day

Answer (score 1):

Though not a single word, ***"time of day"*** is used when referring to a particular part of the day, as in your examples.

> "What ***time of day*** did the crime occur?".
>
> "Early morning."

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrary divisions of time are often called *periods*.

Sometimes the word *hour* itself is used, as a synecdoche, to represent part of a day. Cf. *the morning hour*, *the midnight hour*, *the dinner hour*, etc.